# How can I export vertex paint to Unity?

Tags: vertex-paint

How can I paint an object in Vertex paint and then export it to Unity, keeping it's colour?

Comment: I finally figured it out.
Anyone wondering can follow this tutorial:
http://screencast.com/t/x4UTSnpqtTB